# Highlight the highest value and lowest value in foreach loop

Tags: php

How can I highlight the highest and lowest values in PHP foreach  ?
Here is a simple example, the $results are SQL results in array.
I would like to highlight the highest value and lowest value with simple css, like a background colour.

```
<h3>Camera </h3>

<table class="table">
<tbody>


<tr>
<td>Rear Camera Megapixel</td>
<?php foreach ($results as $result){ ?>
    <td> <strong><?php echo $result['rear_camera']; ?></strong> </td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>Front Camera Megapixel</td>
<?php foreach ($results as $result){ ?>
    <td> <strong><?php echo $result['front_camera']; ?></strong> </td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Original result

[image]

Expected result

[image]

How can I detect high and low value within the `foreach`. Or should I do it before giving data to `foreach` ?

Comment: Unless you have a time machine that lets you modifiy already created output again later on, of course you need to determine them before the loop.

Comment: @CBroe, ok, then let me create the time machine first... ;-)

Comment: Show us your queries.  Why not add `MIN()` and `MAX()` to your sql?  Otherwise, you'll need to iterate the result sets with `min()` and `max()` before looping.

Answer (score 0):

This is code should work:

```
 <?php 
$results = array(1, 2, 3, 44, 54, 56, 122, 34, 9);
$max_value = max($results);
$min_value = min($results);
foreach($results as $result){
    if ($result == $max_value) {
        echo '<td style="background-color: green;">'.$result.'</td>';
    }
    elseif ($result == $min_value){
        echo '<td style="background-color: red;">'.$result.'</td>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<td>'.$result.'</td>'; 
    }

    
}?>
```

You can easily concatenate a string using `.` instead of writing php again and again.

Comment: "_Try this_" and "_I hope it works_" are not part of good educational answers.  Every answer should be explained with the intent to educate and empower the OP and thousands of future researchers.

Comment: Why would any good developer call `$max_value = max($results);
    $min_value = min($results);` **inside** of a loop?  `else if` (as two words) is a violation of PSR-12 coding standards.  The `<span>` tags are useless DOM bloat, add classes to the `<td>`.

Comment: thanks for your comment i will surely try to improve myself.

Answer (score 0):

It is never too early to begin grooming a user about how to improve their Stack Overflow Citizenship.  So, before I start into resolving this question, I want to explain why your question is not a great fit for Stack Overflow.

You have posted a "requirements dump".  You have provided some input data and your expected output, but there isn't a scratch of effort.  I mean, you have shown that you know how to loop and echo, but there isn't so much as a conditional expression nor any attempt to generate the min/max values.  This means that you have not researched and tried enough.

The truth is, your question is comprised of several basic techniques (this makes your question "Too Broad / Needs More Focus") -- all of which will be duplicate questions on Stack Overflow.  Even if Stack Overflow didn't have at least 5 separate pages devoted to each of the basic techniques, the php manual would have given you sufficient information to solve this problem.

1. How to isolate a column of data from a result set into a flat array
2. How to find the min and max value in an array
3. How to conditionally style an element

You see, if you would have posted code to show that you know how to successfully achieve all of these subtasks, then you would have working code.  When you have working code, but you want to know if it can be refined, then you have a question that qualifies as a question on Code Review.

If you found yourself stuck with one of the basic techniques listed above, then it is your responsibility to isolate the exact point in your code where you are stuck, so that your question is not "Too Broad".  In the case of this specific question, if you would have been stuck with just one of the techniques, we could have resolved your question by providing a duplicate page.  This is ideal for Stack Overflow because we are able to resolve your question without generating any needless/redundant pages on the website (you win, Stack Overflow wins, and fewer volunteers waste their time reading a new duplicate question).

As for resolving your question, there will be several different ways to achieve what you need.  I recommend keeping "processing code" separate from "displaying code".  In professional applications, you would not have processing code in the same file as the displaying code.  (One of the most common/trending structures is MVC - where data is collected in the Model then prepared and passed to the View via the Controller.)

Also, you should try to use as little html markup as possible.  The fewer tags you use, the easier it will be for you to manage/style them.  Use a `class` instead of inline styling to provide a cleaner finished script.  A class like `table` on a tag called `table` is not very informative -- it should speak in a unique way about what kind of styling or behavior it is going to have.  If all of your `<table>` tags in the document have a `class="table"` declaration, then just remove it entirely and use the `table` selector in your css.  If there is something special about your tables, then use semantic language to clarify this.

There will be many ways to code this up.  If you like a functional coding style, you would use `array_column()`, `min()`, `max()` for clarity.  If you like micro-optimation for performance / computational simplicity, you would use a loop with iterated conditions to derive the min and max values.

You should also consider the real possibility that the min value is the same as the max value.  In this case, which color/class should be applied?  I can only arbitrarily guess, so my snippet will give the max value the styling priority.

Here is one way to go about it:

```
$details['Rear Camera Megapixels']['values'] = array_column($result, 'rear_camera');
$details['Rear Camera Megapixels'][min($details['Rear Camera Megapixels']['values'])] = 'minValue';
// max will potentially overwrite the min element
$details['Rear Camera Megapixels'][max($details['Rear Camera Megapixels']['values'])] = 'maxValue';
$details['Front Camera Megapixels']['values'] = array_column($result, 'front_camera');
$details['Front Camera Megapixels'][min($details['Front Camera Megapixels']['values'])] = 'minValue';
// max will potentially overwrite the min element
$details['Front Camera Megapixels'][max($details['Front Camera Megapixels']['values'])] = 'maxValue';

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="<?php echo count($result) + 1; ?>">Camera</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($details as $spec => $data) { ?>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $spec; ?></th>
                <?php foreach ($data['values'] as $value) {
                     printf(
                         '<td%s>%s</td>',
                         isset($data[$value]) ? " class=\"{$data[$value]}\"" : '',
                         $value
                     );
                } ?>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then in your external .css file, you would have declarations resembling:

```
.table td.maxValue {
    background-color: green;
    color: darkgreen;
}
.table td.minValue {
    background-color: pink;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: @Hyma have you abandoned this page as well? You should endeavor to progress every question that you ask to a system-recognized resolution.